# House Centipede

Tags: pest-control, pest

The number of insects shown in the image below is growing in my home. In order to know how to fight with their growth, I need to know its name, so I search for the rest. What is the name if this insect?

[image]

**Update**:

Thanks everyone for pointers. Here is the detail:

http://www.thaltech.com/houseblog/2009/05/14/house-centipede-scutigera-coleoptrata/

It is called "House Centipede"

Comment: It's a centipede.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on Google using the name "centipede". It will reveal pictures that look almost exactly like the one that you posted.

Centipedes generally feed on other insects, spiders, cockroaches and others. The first step in control is to try to remove these food sources for the centipedes. Reducing moisture sources is also part of the first steps process. If an infestation is large it may be advisable to seek the services of a professional exterminator. A professional will locate the infestation and use a combination of chemical and non-chemical methods to eradicate the infestation.

Note that handling centipedes should be avoided as some species can give bites that are very painful.

Comment: I agree that if a heavy infestation a pro may be needed but this looks closer to a "silver fish" bug that we had trouble with in Ohio. We used a lawn and home product called seven? Don't know if it is still available but it took them out in a few weeks but that was many years ago.